# Converting 1 array of objects into a nested array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have this:

```
var arr = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];
```

And I'd like to get to this.

```
[[{type:"orange", title:"First"},
{type:"orange", title:"Second"}],

[{type:"banana", title:"Third"},
{type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}]]
```

I've seen a lot for getting to this:

```
{orange: 
[[{type:"orange", title:"First"},
{type:"orange", title:"Second"}], 
banana: 
[{type:"banana", title:"Third"},
{type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}]}
```

But it doesn't help my situation, I need it to be arrays inside an array.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: We need to know how these arrays are getting built. Theres not enough info here to respond to.

Comment: data is being imported in from a SQL server and the process cannot be changed on that end

Comment: if you can get the second, just get the `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one more step, you can map it to the format you want.

```
var arr = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];


const typeDictionary = {}

for (item of arr) {
  if (!typeDictionary[item.type]) {
    typeDictionary[item.type] = [item]
  } else {
    typeDictionary[item.type].push(item)
  }
}

// This is the final missing step
const finalResult = Object.values(typeDictionary)

console.log('finalResult', finalResult)

finalResult [
  [
    { type: 'orange', title: 'First' },
    { type: 'orange', title: 'Second' }
  ],
  [
    { type: 'banana', title: 'Third' },
    { type: 'banana', title: 'Fourth' }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this strategy

- Find all the unique types, `['orange','banana']`
- For each unique type `Array#filter` the original array
- **DONE**

```js
const input = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];

const output = [...new Set(input.map(o => o.type))]
    .map( type => input.filter(o => o.type === type) )

console.log( output );
```

Alternatively, you could use `Array#reduce` as follows:

```js
const input = [
    {type:"orange", title:"First"},
    {type:"orange", title:"Second"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Third"},
    {type:"banana", title:"Fourth"}
];

const output = input.reduce((prev, {type,title}) => {
    let x = prev.findIndex(ar => ar[0].type === type);
    if( x > -1 ) {
        prev[x].push({type,title});
    } else {
        prev.push([{type,title}])
    }
    return prev;
}, []);
    

console.log( output );
```

Comment: This is far less efficient than a standard group-by (O(n*m) vs O(n)), and also this question is a duplicate multiple times over.